# finding a number within a range within an if statement

Tags: if-statement, range, excel-2010

I am attempting to create an IF statement that will use the contents of a cell (A1) within a range (G2:G11), which if found will show the word "Multi", otherwise blank "".

The formula I am attempting to use is =IF(A2=G2:G11,"Multi","").  I can find the first number within the range, but no other number within the range when I tested it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Than you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `COUNTIF` will do it:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G2:G11,A1),"Multi","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not too far off. What you want is an array formula

```
=IF(OR(A2=G2:G11), "Multi", "")
```

When in the cell with that formula by single-clicking or hitting F2, hit `CTL-SHIFT-ENTER` simultaneously. When you do this, you will notice curly brackets on the outside of the formula. Like this

```
{=IF(OR(A2=G2:G11), "Multi", "")}
```

which indicates that you have an array formula.